# Install vaderSentiment--- Mac user

Tags: jupyter

I am new to use Jupyter from Anaconda. I try to [run this column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3Wp8.png) , it has an error. I should install vaderSentiment.

I do not know how to install it.